# How could I judge if two photos are identical with some brightness difference

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have some photo pairs, the objects in some of which are different in details, while others are identical. However, even the photo pairs with identical objects have some difference in the illuminations or photo qualities (due to the unstable camera state), though the structures and details of the object are identical.

I need to distinguish those with identical objects with those with changed objects, and not impacted by the condition of light or camera quality. How could I do this?

========

Edit: 
Here is a pair that has identical object:

[image] [image]

And here is a pair that has object with different detail:

[image] [image]

Even the first pair would have differences in light conditions or other non-content differences, but these are not expected to impact my results. How could I do this please ?

Comment: Providing representative sample images would probably help!

Comment: @MarkSetchell I updated my question :)

Comment: I think you need to extract some features invariant to the different light conditions in order to compare. You could just pick just the color, use edge detection (e.g. Canny or just a convolution with an edge detection kernel), corner detection (e.g. Harris)... However you will have to think how you want to compare them and what thresholds do you use to consider two images to be "the same".

Comment: To add to the previous comment, using the HSV or the LAB color space allows you to compare the colors: you just have to check specific channels (eg. have a higher threshold on the L channel in LAB, since that's what stores the "lightness").

Answer (score 1):

You can use global Lucas-Kanade algorithm (original paper "Lucas-Kanade 20 Years On: A Unifying Framework") for matching images without features. Richard Szeliski say it parametric (global) motion.
It returns transform matrix A: shift, scale, affine or homography. And some values in this matrix say that pictures are not identical:

```
Scale: A[0][0] != 1 or A[1][1] != 1
Shift horizontal and vertical: A[0][2] != 0 and A[1][2] != 0
Rotation: A[0][1] != 0 and A[1][0] != 0
```

They are several implementation of the algorithm - [for example](https://github.com/cheind/image-align).
Addition: opencv_contrib has [reg module](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/reg) with same functions.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize all images to the same average brightness.